# Configure JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, api, express, joi

I created a schema with Joi and want a JSON response (when POSTing) that matches my schema. Problem is: I have to give it a parent(in my example "data:" (I know, I can name it how I want) which I don't want to. The schema's attributes should stand alone inside the JSON. But without giving it a parent, it (`Object.assign(value)`) doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
.post((req,res,next) => {
  let data = req.body;
  Joi.validate(data, schema, (err, value) => {

    res.json({
              data: Object.assign(value)
            });
  });

})
```

expected:

```
{
    "title": "dasdawdasfasd",
    "textshort": "wasser",
    "textlong": "",
    "imgwidth": null,
    "imgheight": null,
    "imgsrc": "",
    "views": 0,
    "keywords": []
}
```

actual:

```
{
  "data": {
    "title": "dasdawdasfasd",
    "textshort": "wasser",
    "textlong": "",
    "imgwidth": null,
    "imgheight": null,
    "imgsrc": "",
    "views": 0,
    "keywords": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return data

```
.post((req,res,next) => {
  Joi.validate(data, schema, (err, value) => {
       res.json(value);
  });

 })
```